# MY SQL compare statement! Does not work the compare statement

Tags: php, mysql

i have create a database with three tables. I have a table "field" which has an id_field from 1-5 and a table name slot which has start and end times. When i want to show all the available fields and times is okay but i when i want to show the field with id value 1 is still showing all the fields!!!!!

Here is my code:

```
echo("<select name='selSlot'>");
$mysql_link = mysql_connect("localhost","root","*********");
$db_select = mysql_select_db("nuevo", $mysql_link);
$query = "SELECT * FROM field WHERE id_field = 1 CROSS JOIN slot WHERE (id_field,id_slot) ".
"NOT IN(Select field_slot,res_slot From reservation WHERE res_date = '"
     .$today['year']."-".$today['mon']."-".$today['mday']."') ORDER by id_field,id_slot";
$result = mysql_query($query)
    or die ("Query '$query' failed with error message: " . mysql_error ());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo "apoel";
while ($row) {
    echo("<option value='" .$row['id_field'].",".$row['id_slot']."'>".$row['description'].
        " ".$row['start_time']."-".$row['end_time']." </option>");
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
}
echo("</select>");
```

I dont know why it doesnt show me only the field with id one and is still showing me all the fields!!!!

Comment: You need to explain what the problem is better. Please read this guide on how to ask better questions on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Your query has two `WHERE` clauses:

```
.... WHERE id_field = 1   CROSS JOIN slot    WHERE ...
```

It should result in a database error. Proper syntax is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM field 
    CROSS JOIN slot
WHERE id_field = 1 
  AND  (id_field,id_slot)
...
```

Comment: when i run it like this it still showing me all the fields.. It doesnt give me any error

Comment: No, that can't be true. Print (echo) the `$query` before you run it and post it in the question.

Comment: Hmm, it doesnt print anything!!! what should i do to get the id_field 1 where i need to compare it to get the right results!!?

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!!1 pfff finally!!!! I have been working to finish this reservation system for 3 weeks now and now is finished!!! THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!!!!